# How to design calculated column formula for multiplication based on nested IFs?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, calculated-column-formula

One of the SharePoint forms I am working with, i have two columns:
!. Choice Column with choices: 2.5 ,3,4 and 6. The second column is called Quantity of type number where user enters a value in number format like 1,10, 20 etc.

Now based on these two column inputs I would like to create a calculated column which would work as:
If choice column populated value is 2.5 then calculated column formula should be: 7.5 * Quantity column value that user enters.
If choice column value is 3 then formula becomes: 9 * Quantity value.
If choice column value is 4 then formula becomes: 10 * Quantity value
If choice column value is 6 then formula would be : 16 * Quantity value.

Can someone please help me with the formula that I can use ti build the calculated column, thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create and test formula in Excel and then copy/paste them into SharePoint calculated columns and update the column names or values to use.  It can be easer to create in Excel so you can expand the editor window and get the brackets right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

`=IF(ChoiceC="2.5",7.5,IF(ChoiceC="3",9,IF(ChoiceC="4",10,IF(ChoiceC="6",16,0))))*Quantity`